# API not accessible when contextroot is present

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 Application API and UI as separate war file currently in development mode both are deployed in same port.
http://localhost:9080/ui
and
http://localhost:9080/api

deployed on tomcat 9.0.53
Openjdk 11

i was having trouble to get the data from api.
later application started to work but i know that's an workaround.

when my API is deployed without an context root(http://localhost:9080/authenticate) its working,
but with a context root(http://localhost:9080/***api***/authenticate), my UI application is throwing below error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:9080/api/authenticate
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1909)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
at com.edge.service.common.ApiHandler.post(ApiHandler.java:55)
at com.edge.service.common.ApiHandler.parseAsObject(ApiHandler.java:86)
at com.edge.service.login.LoginService.authenticateuser(LoginService.java:44)
```

Comment: any suggestions for the above question

Comment: Can you update the question to share the client code from your UI application where you invoke the said rest call that throws this issue.